# Retrieve String from JSON in Android using JSONArray

Tags: android, json, parsing, http

This is my json code: `{"teams" : ["Real Madrid", "Bayern Munich"]}`

Now I want to parse the values of the "teams" in android.

I have tried to parse it by this way, but it didn't work:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("teams");
String team1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString();
String team2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).toString();
```

Please tell me how to make it to work.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? are you getting in error ?

Comment: whats queryArray? I dont see the variable jsonArray being used

Comment: no, I don't get error, but I don't get the value too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the package org.json, You should try

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("teams");
   String team1 = jsonArray.getString(0);
   String team2 = jsonArray.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("teams");

String team1 = jsonArray.optString(0);
String team2 = jsonArray.optString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the structure of the JSON which you are getting. Because there is an  array but there is no object.Objects are inside curly braces {}. So by specifying index location you cannot retrieve the value. You might need to update the JSON format.